# C2248 error when using smart pointers in singleton class

Tags: c++, singleton, smart-pointers

In below code I'm having C2248 error. When I replace smart pointers with the raw pointers it compiles. However I want to use smart pointer std::shared_ptr<> object.
How can I correct this error when using smart pointer?

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <memory>

    class GameSetting{
    inline static std::shared_ptr<GameSetting> _instance;
    unsigned int _brightness;
    unsigned int _width;
    unsigned int _heigth;
    GameSetting():_brightness{150}, _width{300}, _heigth{200}
   {}

   public:
   static std::shared_ptr<GameSetting> getInstance(){
    if(! _instance)
        _instance=std::make_shared<GameSetting>();
    return _instance;
   }


  void setBrightness(unsigned brightness){_brightness=brightness;}
  void setWidth(unsigned  int width){_width=width;}
  void setHeight(unsigned int height){_heigth=height;}

  unsigned int getBrightness()const{return  _brightness;}
  unsigned int getWidth()const{return _width;}
  unsigned int getHeigth()const{return _heigth;}

  void displaySettings()const{
    std::cout<<"brigthness: "<<_brightness<<'\n'<<"width: "<<_width
            <<'\n'<<"heigth: "<<_heigth<<"\n\n";
  }
  };



  int main()
  {
  std::shared_ptr<GameSetting> setting=GameSetting::getInstance();
  setting->displaySettings();

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `make_shared<GameSetting>()` call requires access to the default constructor of your `GameSetting` class; however, that constructor is implicitly declared as `private` (which is the default access specifier for class members).

To fix this issue, just add the `public:` access specifier before your constructor definition:

```cpp
class GameSetting {
    inline static std::shared_ptr<GameSetting> _instance;
    unsigned int _brightness;
    unsigned int _width;
    unsigned int _heigth;
public: // Anything before this is "private" by default
    GameSetting() :_brightness{ 150 }, _width{ 300 }, _heigth{ 200 }
    {}
public:
    static std::shared_ptr<GameSetting> getInstance()
    {
        if (!_instance)
            _instance = std::make_shared<GameSetting>();
        return _instance;
    }
   // ... the rest of you class definition
```

Alternatively, if you wish/need to keep your `GameSetting` constructor private (as is common with singleton classes), then you can replace the call to `std::make_shared` with a direct 'call' to the `std::shared_ptr` constructor (and an assignment of the result). Thus, your `getInstance` function would then be:

```cpp
    static std::shared_ptr<GameSetting> getInstance()
    {
        if (!_instance)
            _instance = std::shared_ptr<GameSetting>{new GameSetting};
        return _instance;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Adrian, however in a singleton pattern the constructor must be private, so I have to sort this problem out in a different approach.

Comment: Yes Adrian, this worked. Thank you very much. In this form this code can be used. For further research I will look up how to use this code with std::make_shared<> In  the form that you suggested I believe there's still no memory leak risk.